# Добавления списка в список

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, список, списки

Есть список, в котором еще есть списки.
Например:

```
Date = ['Команда1', 
        ['Даты', ['27-28.04.2019', '20.04.2019'], 
         ['События',['Событие1', 'Событие2']]]]
```

Я знаю, как добавить просто значение в список Date, но не знаю, как запихнуть значение в список, который идет после слова "Даты".

Как написать `Date.append()` правильно или что можно использовать вместо него? Я пробовал `Date.extend()`, но этот метод разбивает строку на символы и просто их вставляет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Date[1].insert(1, 'XXXXXX')
```

или динамически:

```
Date[1].insert(Date[1].index('Даты') + 1, 'XXXXXX')
```

результат:

```
In [69]: Date
Out[69]:
['Команда1',
 ['Даты',
  'XXXXXX',
  ['27-28.04.2019', '20.04.2019'],
  ['События', ['Событие1', 'Событие2']]]]
```

---

**UPDATE:**

```
In [80]: Date[1][Date[1].index('Даты')+1].append('11.11.2011')

In [81]: Date
Out[81]:
['Команда1',
 ['Даты',
  ['27-28.04.2019', '20.04.2019', '11.11.2011'],
  ['События', ['Событие1', 'Событие2']]]]
```

Comment: А если, например, где числа? Как туда добавить?

Comment: @V.Bychkov, какие числа? Вы имеете ввиду даты?

Comment: да. Простите, что не указал

Answer (score 0):

Вот так:

```
Date[1].insert(2, "Значение")
# Выведет: ['Команда1', ['Даты', ['27-28.04.2019', '20.04.2019'], 'Значение', ['События', ['Событие1', 'Событие2']]]]
```

Чтобы было понятнее:

```
print(Date[1])
# Выведет: ['Даты', ['27-28.04.2019', '20.04.2019'], ['События', ['Событие1', 'Событие2']]]
```

Команда Date[1].insert(2, "Значение") вставит "Значение" по индексу 2, после ['27-28.04.2019', '20.04.2019']